# How to add custom class to each Slick Carousel item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have a slick slider on my site and its working.

What i need is to add a custom class to each item when the carousel renders.

ex: This is one done with owl carousel

if you use the following jQuery here:
http://codepen.io/OwlFonk/pen/dpjhB

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var carousel = jQuery("#owl-demo");
    carousel.owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom: [[0,5]],
    navigation : false, autoPlay : 10000, mouseDrag : true, touchDrag : true, pagination : false, rewindNav: true,
     afterAction: function(el){
       //remove class active
       for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
           {
                this.$owlItems.removeClass('active' + i)
           }
       //add class active
       for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
           {
                this.$owlItems.eq(this.currentItem + i).addClass('active' + i)
           }
     }
    });
});
```

you will be able to see what i need.

I cant seem to get it working with Slick.

The reason im using Slick and not Owl is because Owl doesnt have infinite scrolling and Owl 2 is too buggy.

I would consider using Owl 2 if i can do the same as above but they changed the script so much i cant get it working.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same exact problem...

Comment: @LyndonJohnson I actually did get it working using bxslider.